# (cURL / PHP) API Response - Invalid HTTP method used

Tags: php, api, curl

Hopefully a simple question, I have tried to connect to my first REST API using PHP and cURL. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$zooplaKey = "mykey";
$postcode = $_GET['postcode'];

$sendData = array('api_key' => $zooplaKey,
                  'postcode' => $postcode,
                  'output_type' => "postcode");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/average_area_sold_price.js');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sendData);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$raw_json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$zooplaInfo = json_decode($raw_json, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($zooplaInfo);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Run exactly as above I get a return of:

> Array
>   (
>       [error_string] => Invalid HTTP method used
>       [error_code] => 2
>   )

Uncommenting `//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);` or `//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);` just returns a blank screen.

By using the following URL I am able to get a valid result (obviously I have had to blank the api key so this link is for structure purposes only) http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/average_area_sold_price.xml?api_key=mykey&postcode=ws12dn&output_type=postcode

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Zoopla API Documentation](http://developer.zoopla.com/docs/read/Average_area_sold_price), what you are trying to do is to:

> Retrieve the average sale price for houses in a particular area.

Retrieval is done using a GET method in the REST standard. By using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, cURL will automatically convert your request to a POST, which is invalid for retrieval. You should remove the post fields part, and do that instead:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://full/url?'.http_build_query($sendData));
```

Comment: Thanks, from other things I had followed I had only seen POSTFIELDS, works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in the URL are being passed as GET. I would try appending the parameters to the CURLOPT_URL instead of putting them in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS array. The remote service probably requires the values be in the query string rather than being posted.